# decode_png returns shape of 3 dimensions of question marks

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to read an image and convert it into tensor using the following code

```
img_path = <image directory> 
img_raw = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
img_tensor = tf.image.decode_png(img_raw)
```

and when I try to print its shape

```
print(img_tensor.shape)
```

it gives me 3 question marks instead of values:

```
(?, ?, ?)
```

why it doesn't work and how to fix this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code, you just need to execute the operation with a `tf.Session()`. This works for me:

```
img_path = <image directory> 
img_raw = tf.io.read_file(img_path)
img_tensor = tf.image.decode_png(img_raw)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(img_tensor).shape)
```

Comment: That's worked thanks very much, can you tell me what does that mean, the tf.Session()??

Comment: In Tensorflow 1.xx, a static graph is build in the background. Then, when you want to execute parts of the graph, you have to run a `tf.Session()` and run the nodes for which you want the outputs.